# LDAP decrypt function throwing undefined offset error

Tags: 7, multi-sites

The error shows up on all of the pages of a "secondary" site in a multi-site configuration. The main, default, site does not show the error. The complete error message is:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _ldap_servers_decrypt() (line 97 of
>   D:\ms4w\Apache\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\ldap\ldap_servers\ldap_servers.encryption.inc).

A direct "hit" for that message points to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap/issues/3050620) for the LDAP module and I have done all of the things suggested to no avail.

The line of code in question reads:

```
list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($input), 2);
```

Displaying the value of `$input` which should be the encrypted password from the database results in `tVIO16QY+vkDieVpCLyAxtU+Ylqoqw==`. When `base64_decode` is applied the resulting value does not contain `::` which is why the error is being thrown.

All that said the LDAP configuration is correct and works as it should. Short of deleting all of the LDAP related modules and starting over with them is there anything else I might be able to try?